# jquery Autocomplete feature is not working for newly added Table row-->cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/? in HTML table cell. I am adding new rows dynamically by clicking button. But autocomplete is working only for the first row which gets created when page is loaded initially. jquery autocomplete function is not getting called for all newly added rows . How to accomplish this?

HTML Table with Autocomplete script:

```
    <table id="dataTable" name="dataTable" border="1" WIDTH="50">
    <col width="40">
        <tr>
            <th>Prog Filter</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td WIDTH="40">
                    <input type="text" name="ProgFilter" id="ProgFilter" style="display:table-cell; width:40px" />
                </td>
        </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC", ];
        $("#ProgFilter").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

Javascript which is adding rows:

```
     function addRow(tableID){
var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount=table.rows.length;
var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount=table.rows[1].cells.length;
for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++)
{
var newcell=row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type)
    {
    case"text":newcell.childNodes[0].value="";break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The usual way is to construct a new widget for every new `input` tag you create

Comment: I added autocomplete function after creating row. Now it is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Working JS which calls autocomplete functions for each row based on TD's class:

```
    function addRow(tableID){
var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount=table.rows.length;
var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount=table.rows[1].cells.length;
for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++)
{
var newcell=row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type)
    {
    case"text":newcell.childNodes[0].value="";break;
    case"checkbox":newcell.childNodes[0].checked=false;break;
    case"select-one":newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex=0;break;
    }
            $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme",
        ];
        $( ".FilerClass" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
}

}
```